# Find String and Replace word and remove subsequent words PHP

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove words after a certain word in a string in php.

I'm using this to replace:

```
$text = "Example University School of Science";
$oldUni = "University";
$newUni = "University%";
$text = str_replace($oldUni , $newUni , $text);
```

I want to have just the words that precede 'University', and it can be an undefined number of words. So the above would look like 'Example University%'.

I've tried str_replace but that just replaces the occurences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = "Example University School of Science";

$var="University";

$pos=stripos($text,$var);


$text_new=substr($text,0,$pos+strlen($var));

echo $text_new."%";
```

Answer (score 2):

Abu you can either use [nevermind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2045185/nevermind)'s code or if you are using PHP >= 5.3.0 the following code can be used:-

```
$text = "Example of the University School of Science";
$oldUni = "University";

$user = strstr($text, $oldUni, true);
echo $user . $oldUni .'%'; // prints name
```

While the function [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) did exist before, the third parameter(true) was only added in PHP 5.3.0

Reference:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
$array = explode ($text, "University");
$newText = $array[0];
```

Hope that helps :)